# Flutter Changenotifier provider getting disposed after closing and opening of bottom model sheet

Tags: flutter, bloc, provider, flutter-bloc, changenotifier

In my Flutter app, I have this `ChangeNotifier` provider. On the homepage a `ChangeNotifier` is created.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<UserTeam>(create: (_) => UserTeam()),
```

I am setting the value for this provider on button press using this code below.

```
late UserTeam _userTeam;
_userTeam = Provider.of<UserTeam>(context);
UserTeam _userTeam = UserTeam(userDetails: test, pageDetails: 3);
_userTeam.setUserTeam(_userTeam);
```

I am passing this `ChangeNotifier` provider to the bottom sheet.

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context2) {
            return BlocProvider.value(
              value: BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context),
              child: BlocProvider.value(
                value: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context),
                child: MultiProvider(
                  providers: [
                    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserTeam?>(create: (_) => _userTeam),
                  ],
                  child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter mystate) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: const teamSearch(),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
```

When opening the bottom model sheet for first time, `ChangeNotifier` `UserTeam` is available. After closing and opening it's getting disposed and throwing an error as this code shows below.

> Another exception was thrown: A UserTeam was used after
> being disposed.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The code is confusing `Provider` on which variable to use, please change variable names

```dart
final userTeam = Provider.of<UserTeam>(context);
UserTeam _userTeam = UserTeam(userDetails: 'test, pageDetails: 3);
userTeam.setUserTeam(_userTeam);
```

Rather than creating a whole new `Provider` later in `showModalBottomSheet` create a value provider

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider.value<UserTeam?>(value: _userTeam),
```

Comment: Hello usama, many thanks for the response. let me brief it again. I have userteam page which set the value for changenotifier, once value is set changenotifier shows user page. In user page i have button to open bottomsheet, in bottom sheet also i can access the changenotifier value. after closing and reopening the bottomsheet changenotifier is not available.

Comment: Is the solution above is not working?

Comment: No it's not changenotifier provider getting disposed from the userteam page when i am opening and closing the modelsheet

Comment: There has to be more code included to get the idea about what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I solved this by passing function as parameter to bottommodelsheet. function parameter contains changenotifier model class with value, and am returning the function with value back to the main page.